# R Script that works fine, does not run in knitr - issue with %>%

Tags: r, dplyr, knitr

I am having a R script which runs perfectly (including `dplyr` and `magrittr`). However, when I source the script in my .Rmd and knit it, I get the error

```
Error in missingStat(oil_condensed_usefulCols): could not find function "%>%" Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> missingStat Execution paused
```

`missingStat` is one of my functions. What is wrong here?

Comment: Do you import the `magrittr` library also in your .Rmd file?

Comment: No, I import it in the script - as I do with all the other libraries. Now I tried importing it before I run the script, but the error (unsurprisingly) stays.

Comment: do you cache your Chunks? If so make sure that the one where you load the packages and your function is not cached as this can lead to this kind of problems.

Comment: @SarinaJ.: So far I am not caching deliberately. Maybe without being deliberate - is there a way to check?.

Comment: Solution: Put the `library(...)`s into the .Rmd. But why can't my packages be in the script? Are scripts scopes and `library(...)`s not transfered to the .Rmd scope? (I'd love an answer to accept ;-).)

Comment: I think caching not deliberately is not really possible as you have to specify it in the chunk options. I am mostly working with Rnw files so I can't help you with the reason why you have to load the package again. As far as my experiences are with sourcing in Rnw files they work also if you haven't loaded the extra packages but it might be that I just by accident did that all the time.

Comment: @make42 would it be possible to provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem? I am not sure if you were using `source` or `knitr::read_chunk`, or explicitly including `magrittr`.

Answer (score 4):

Try moving the call to `library(dplyr)` into the named code chunk in your R script, rather than putting it into the `Rmd` file. You'll also want to disable caching for the chunks from the external R script, or changes you make to the script may not appear in the knitted output.

I am able to reproduce the error using 'knitr::read_chunk', and an external file that contains a named chunk, but has the `library` calls outside of the chunk.

Here's a minimal external R script that uses `dplyr`, call it `dplyr_cars.R`:

```
library(dplyr)
## ---- speed-13
cars %>% 
  filter(speed > 13) %>% 
  summary
```

Note the named chunk, created with `## ---- <name>`, and that `library(dplyr)` is above the name.

Then, in `externalize_dplyr.Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "Externalize Dplyr"
date: "January 20, 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r cache=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk('dplyr_cars.R')
```

```{r speed-13}
```
````

Knitting this will produce the error you reported:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "%>%"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
```

But if you move the library declaration inside the named chunk, it works.

```
## ---- speed-13
library(dplyr)
cars %>% 
  filter(speed > 13) %>% 
  summary
```